# Я хочу сделать рычаг в unity 2d Platformer

Tags: unity3d

Я хочу сделать рычаг в unity 2d, но как сделать чтобы на него можно было нажимать на Андроид?
Компонент Button, если его добавить на обычный 2д спрайт, то кнопка не нажимается?
Если кто знает, подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компонент Button будет бесполезен, попробуй это

```
public bool LeverTurn;
public GameObject Lever;`

public void OnMouseDown()
{
LeverTurn = !LeverTurn;
}
```

Это должно работать. Нужно прикрепить этот код к рычагу. Дальше можешь добавлять код анимации или что захочешь

Comment: Спасибо, но будет ли это работать на андроид